# Can we create a file or directory with other user and group ownership

Tags: linux, permissions, mkdir

I was wondering if I can create a file or directory from root login with the user and group ownership of a random user account.

Like,

```
root@something# mkdir folder
root@something# ls -l 
root root folder
```

But, is there any syntax to follow so that I get the desired result as below

```
root@something# mkdir folder u:admin g:admin
root@something# ls -l
admin admin folder
```

Sorry for the stupid `mkdir` command with `u:` and `g:` tried my best to explain it simple.

**OS: CentOS 7**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the root access, you can change the permissions/ownerships of directories and groups.
    chown -> changes ownership
    chmod -> changes permissions

You can create the directory from the root and change the ownership using

```
sudo chown username:group1 dirname
```

If you want to change ownership recursively, just add -R

```
sudo chown -R username:group1 dirname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file by using the install command

```
sudo install -o my-user -g my-user-group -m 644 /dev/null /path_to_your_file
```

-o: owner
-g: group
-m: mode

check more at `man install`